# Bootstrap nav's background-color not changing when active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi guys when I click on my bootstrap's nav-bar the background-color(of my nav bar) is not changing according to my css code. please help!

carousel.js/carousel.css and login.html

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#mainCarousel').carousel({
interval: 4000
});

var clickEvent = false;
$('#mainCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function () {
clickEvent = true;
$('.nav li').removeClass('active');
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
}).on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
if (!clickEvent) {

var count = $('#indexmenu').children().length - 1;
var current = $('#indexmenu li.active');
current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
var id = parseInt(current.next().data('slide-to'));
if (isNaN(id)) {
$('#indexmenu li').first().addClass('active');
}
}
clickEvent = false;
});
});
```

```css
body
{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
#myCarousel .nav a small
{
    display: block;
}
#myCarousel .nav
{
    background: #eee;
}
.nav-justified > li > a
{
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.nav-pills>li[data-slide-to="0"].active a { background-color: #16a085; }
.nav-pills>li[data-slide-to="1"].active a { background-color: #e67e22; }
.nav-pills>li[data-slide-to="2"].active a { background-color: #2980b9; }
.nav-pills>li[data-slide-to="3"].active a { background-color: #8e44ad; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="carousel.css">
<script src="carousel.js"></script>

</head>



<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/16a085/ffffff&text=About Us">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>
                        Headline</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
                        tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem
                        ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Item -->
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/e67e22/ffffff&text=Projects">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>
                        Headline</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
                        tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem
                        ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Item -->
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/2980b9/ffffff&text=Portfolio">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>
                        Headline</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
                        tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem
                        ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Item -->
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/8e44ad/ffffff&text=Services">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>
                        Headline</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
                        tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem
                        ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Item -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Carousel Inner -->
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">About<small>Lorem
                ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">Projects<small>Lorem ipsum
                dolor sit</small></a></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">Portfolio<small>Lorem ipsum
                dolor sit</small></a></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"><a href="#">Services<small>Lorem ipsum
                dolor sit</small></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End Carousel -->
</div>



<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>



</html>
```

I think the error is in the css code but please do let me know! cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ID of your main container is `myCarousel` and not `mainCarousel`

Use

```
$('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function () {..});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
interval: 4000
});

var clickEvent = false;
$('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function () {
clickEvent = true;
$('.nav li').removeClass('active');
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
}).on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
if (!clickEvent) {

var count = $('#indexmenu').children().length - 1;
var current = $('#indexmenu li.active');
current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
var id = parseInt(current.next().data('slide-to'));
if (isNaN(id)) {
$('#indexmenu li').first().addClass('active');
}
}
clickEvent = false;
});
});
```

```css
body
{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
#myCarousel .nav a small
{
    display: block;
}
#myCarousel .nav
{
    background: #eee;
}
.nav-justified > li > a
{
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.nav-pills>li[data-slide-to="0"].active a { background-color: #16a085; }
.nav-pills>li[data-slide-to="1"].active a { background-color: #e67e22; }
.nav-pills>li[data-slide-to="2"].active a { background-color: #2980b9; }
.nav-pills>li[data-slide-to="3"].active a { background-color: #8e44ad; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="carousel.css">
<script src="carousel.js"></script>

</head>



<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/16a085/ffffff&text=About Us">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>
                        Headline</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
                        tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem
                        ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Item -->
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/e67e22/ffffff&text=Projects">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>
                        Headline</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
                        tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem
                        ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Item -->
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/2980b9/ffffff&text=Portfolio">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>
                        Headline</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
                        tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem
                        ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Item -->
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/8e44ad/ffffff&text=Services">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>
                        Headline</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
                        tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem
                        ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Item -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Carousel Inner -->
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">About<small>Lorem
                ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">Projects<small>Lorem ipsum
                dolor sit</small></a></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">Portfolio<small>Lorem ipsum
                dolor sit</small></a></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"><a href="#">Services<small>Lorem ipsum
                dolor sit</small></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End Carousel -->
</div>



<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>



</html>
```